# Column width in tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, column-width

I have this table:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,newtxmath} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Scenario descriptions}\label{tab3}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize\linewidth=\hsize } Z *{9}{Z} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly triggering} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly description} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
\addlinespace
Scenario & Condition & Begin & End & Type & Target & Impacted security criteria \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & blablablablabla blab lablabl ablablabla ablablabla & 6\\
\addlinespace
2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\addlinespace
3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\
\addlinespace
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I would like to adjust the "Target" column because there is long text in it.
I know that X columns in a single table are set to the same width but I tried to force the first column width with `>{\hsize=.3\hsize\linewidth=\hsize } Z` but the other column widths don't adapt.

Other question: Do you think it's better to adjust "Scenario" with the `\cmidrule(l)` line ?

Thanks for your help.

Here is an image of the result:
[image]

Comment: the Target column with raggedright format is shown in the answer below-- putting a line above Scenario does not really work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `tabular*`

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}

\caption{Scenario descriptions}\label{tab3}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Anomaly triggering} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly description} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{5-7}
\addlinespace
Scenario & Condition & Begin & End & Type & Target & Impacted security criteria \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering blablablablabla blab lablabl ablablabla ablablabla} & 6\\
\addlinespace
2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\addlinespace
3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\
\addlinespace
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,newtxmath,lipsum} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table*}
        \caption{Scenario descriptions}\label{tab3}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{  *{5}{c}Zc}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly triggering} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly description} \\
            \cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}\cmidrule{1-1}
            \addlinespace
            Scenario & Condition & Begin & End & Type & Target & Impacted security criteria \\
            \midrule
            \addlinespace
            1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \raggedright\lipsum[1] & 6\\
            \addlinespace
            2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
            \addlinespace
            3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\
            \addlinespace
            4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
    
\end{document}
```